# Stability of N-order Thiran delay filter when required passband delay is N+1

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, group-delay, allpass

In [this lecture note](http://users.spa.aalto.fi/vpv/publications/vesan_vaitos/ch3_pt3_allpass.pdf), on page 7 (or page 111, the same page), it is said that the Thiran allpass delay filter of order N with passsband delay N+1 reproduces samples with zero error. I find it hard to believe, but am having hard time proving or disproving otherwise. Is this true?

And the note also says that when required passband delay is N+1, the filter is unstable. Again, I am finding it difficult to prove or disprove it. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you refer to

> It is seen that the error is zero for integral delay values $N- D=-1$ or $N-D= 0$.

This appears to be a typo. The error is zero for $D = N-1$ and $D = N$.

At these values of $D$ the delay is an integer number of samples. For $D = N$ The poles are all at $z=0$ and the all pass chain turns into simple FIR delay line, i.e. $a_0 = 1$ and $a_k = 0, k \neq 0$. For $D = N-1$ the filter is marginally stable and we have $a_0 = a_1 = 1$  and $a_k = 0, k > 1$ . That's easy enough to see of you put $D=N$ into table 3.1

> And the note also says that when required passband delay is N+1, the filter is unstable

It does not say that. It says it's stable for $D > N-1$ and marginally stable at $D = N -1 $. For stability of $D > N$ you should refer back to Thiran's original paper.  The proof for $N-1 < D <= N$ was done "experimentally".

Comment: For D=N+1 (N-D=-1), table 3.1 does not result in $a_0 = 1$, $a_k = 0$. In such a case, would error still be zero? Or are just poles at $z=0$? Or is this a typo in the note and I should read it as N-d=1? Then things make perfect sense...

Comment: Good catch, updated.